# PrimeNG SelectButton with TEMPLATE don't show correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to implement something similar to the example that PrimeNG shows on his website 
[PrimeNG - SelectButton](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/selectbutton)
in the section **Custom Template**. I'm trying to replicate the same. This is my code:

**component.ts**

```
metodos: any[];
selectedMetodo;

constructor() {
    this.metodos = [
      { 'name': 'Tarjeta de crédito','flag': 'pse.png' },
      { 'name': 'PSE', 'flag': 'pse.png' },
      { 'name': 'Efectivo', 'flag': 'pse.png'}
    ];
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<p-selectButton [options]="metodos" [(ngModel)]="selectedMetodo">
    <ng-template let-item>
        <img src="assets/img/pagos/{{item.flag}}" />
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-selectButton>
```

I have this result: [web result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQcI2.png)

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

write this:

```
<p-selectButton [options]="metodos" [(ngModel)]="selectedMetodo" optionLabel="name">
<ng-template let-item>
    <img src="assets/img/pagos/{{item.value.flag}}" />
    <span>{{item.value.name}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in primeng 5.2.0 and below versions. You have to update your primeng version to **5.2.7** Then you can resolve this issue.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-select-btn) is stackblitz. Image broken but you can see the actual result.

**Update**

Fixed image issue as well.